# Zoomed in text going behind image on certain screen resolution (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a coming soon page for a friend using a purchased html template.

The site displays fine on most resolutions (see image 1, 15" 4K: 3840x2160), but on a certain screen resolution and size (see image 2, 13" 4K: 3840x2160) the text looks zoomed in and some of it goes behind the logo image.

[image: Image 1 (15" 4K display)]

[image: Image 2 (13" 4K display)]

Any ideas on how to fix this? I tried adding margin-bottom to the logo, didn't work. Then I tried adding margin top to the "We Are" text, which worked, but move the text down on all screen sizes so it is not centered, not ideal.

Comment: add margin-top to ``.headline``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add negative `margin-top` to you `.logo` div. This will move the logo up so it doesnt go over your text.

```
.logo {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This moves all the main coming soon text down as well on all screens. (Not centered)

Comment: what is supposed to be center?

Comment: The "coming soon text and notify button should all be centered as a group vertically. When I add the margin to the headline it pushes it down. See this [image](https://imgur.com/a/R5Wh3Er)

Comment: I think the real reason it looks funny on the smaller display is that it is being zoomed in. Not sure why it would zoom in like that on a 13" 4K display vs a 15" 4k display as they have the same resolution.

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution as it simply moves the whole logo up. But it is acceptable, thank you.